# Django Equivalent of SqlAlchemy `any` to filter `WHERE EXISTS`

Tags: django, django-models, sqlalchemy, django-orm

I have two models, `Sample` and `Run`. A `Sample` can belong to multiple `Run`s. The `Run` model has `name` that I would like to use to filter `Sample`s on; I would like to find all `Samples` that have a run with a given `name` filter. In SqlAlchemy, I write this like:

```
Sample.query.filter(Sample.runs.any(Run.name.like('%test%'))).all()
```

In Django, I start with:

```
Sample.objects.filter(run__in=Run.objects.filter(name__icontains='test'))
```

or

```
Sample.objects.filter(run__name__icontains='test')
```

However both of these produce duplicates so I must add `.distinct()` to the end.

The Django approach of using `distinct` has terrible performance when there are a large number of predicates (because the `distinct` operation must runs over a large number of possible rows) whereas the SqlAlchemy runs fine. The repeated rows come from repeated `left outer join` from each predicate.

For example:

```
Sample.objects.filter(Q(**{'run__name__icontains': 'alex'}) |
     Q(**{'run__name__icontains': 'baz'}) | ...)
```

**EDIT**: To make this a little more complicated, I do want the ability to have filters like:

```
(Q(**{'run__name__icontains': 'alex'}) | Q(**{'name__icontains': 'alex'})
  & Q(**{'run__name__icontains': 'baz'}) | Q(**{'name__icontains': 'baz'}))
```

which has a SQLAlchemy query like:

```
clause1 = Sample.runs.any(Run.name.like('%alex%')) | Sample.name.like('%test%')
clause2 = Sample.runs.any(Run.name.like('%baz%')) | Sample.name.like('%baz%')
Sample.query.filter(clause1 & clause2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Sample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Run(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample)
```

Since I wasn't able to figure out how to do this without using "distinct", or without using "raw" (in which, if you're forming your own SQL code, and can't rely on the ORM, then what's the point :p), I recommend to try replacing the Django ORM with SQLAlchemy, or use them along-side each other, since theoretically that would work. Sorry I couldn't be of much help :(

Here is a fairly-recent blog post that can help you do that:
http://rodic.fr/blog/sqlalchemy-django/

Comment: Hey, disregard my answer; I don't know if it will work. I'm running tests to see if I can come up with an answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Question: what's wrong with distinct? The filters are lazy-loaded, so it won't evaluate the query except at a specific time:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

All .distinct() does is add SELECT DISTINCT to the SQL query from the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: right now the query being generated takes ~30 seconds to run because it created ~500MB of data (2,097,152 rows) that get filtered down to 1 row.

Comment: Alright, have you considered forming your own SQL? Maybe see what SQLAlchemy outputs (probably in standard out) and modify that for your searches. It's possible that Django ORM isn't perfect.

Comment: This is documentation on how to input raw SQL for the query:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/

Comment: I have tried formatting my own SQL and way able to come up with something MUCH after but the query I had matches what SQLALchemy comes comes up with and that is fundamentally different from the Django ORM (no DISTINCT or joins, uses `EXISTS`).

Comment: Alright, sorry I wasn't able to help you. I think you can technically use SQLAlchemy along-side Django since it seems like the more powerful ORM. I haven't tried it, but it seems like you are probably trying it, and you look like you're on the right track. Anyways, I'm glad I helped, since I learned something today :)